# Does spark-elasticsearch connector support reading data of es index with more than one parallelism

Tags: elasticsearch

I am reading at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html#spark-read

I want to read all the data belonging to an index.

I would like to ask whether this spark-elasticsearch connector support reading with more than one parallelism，so that I could speed up the reading speed.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer. spark-es connector support reading with more than one parallism, the default parallism equals to the number of shards of index.